# Converting CYYMMDD to SAS Date in DB2 via SAS

Tags: sql, db2, sas

I'm looking to convert a date that is in the format of CYYMMDD (where C is either 0 for 20th century or 1 for 21st century) to a standard SAS date. This code will be placed inside of a SAS query using 'proc sql' so that it can compare a SAS date against a date stored in DB2.

Example: Input data=1130101, Output='1Jan2013'd

Examples I've tried are:

```
(substr(t1.'EffectDate'n,4,2)|| '/' || substr(t1.'EffectDate'n,6,2) || '/' || cast(substr(t1.'EffectDate'n,1,3) AS INTEGER) + 1900)
```

That fails to the cast() function (appears it doesn't exist?)

Also tried:

```
convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, right(t1.'EffectDate'n, 6), 12), 101)
```

But varchar(10) doesn't exist.

My query looks like this:

```
proc sql;
create table CLAIMS as select
          t1.CID, 
          t1.MID, 
          t1.DOS 
          OTHER_TABLE.ChangeDate AS EffectDate
      FROM
        SOURCE.REJECTED t1
      INNER JOIN
        EGTASK.OTHER_TABLE
      ON
        t1.DOS >= *Converted_Date*
      [... goes on a couple more lines...]
```

Where *Converted_Date* is what I need.

(However, I should clarify that this particular query/join doesn't necessarily need to be SQL)

Comment: First, there is no need to surround a SAS variable name with single-quotes and the `n` qualifier; `EffectDate` is just fine.  What kind of variable is it (character or numeric)?

Comment: The quotes were leftover from playing around - it's only like that in that statement. The variable is numeric. It is in the format of the input data listed in "Example"

Comment: Sorry this is so complicated but what do the two LIBREFS "SOURCE" and "EGTASK" refer to?  Are they different DB2 connections or is one a SAS library?

Comment: EGTASK is just a place to store temporary tables (EG refers to Enterprise Guide, a SAS GUI program). In this case "SOURCE" is not an external reference, sorry - it is a SAS library (I noted in my original question that this all doesn't necessarily need to be SQL - something I failed to remember originally). 

I now get these errors:

ERROR: Expression using greater than or equal (>=) has components that are of different data types.
ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: SASEffectDate.

Comment: Okay, then take a look at my updated answer.  It shows you how to manipulate that variables in a `CASE` expression.  Just revise it to make a derived table in your main SQL (i.e. `INNER JOIN (SELECT ...)`.  Note that you are now saying your question is 100 percent SAS and does not involve DB2 at all.

Comment: I've integrated it into my select statement (as shown in your example), but it's still complaining with the errors I pasted in my above comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24677/discussion-between-nick-betcher-and-bob-duell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert your variable from it's current coded format into a proper SAS date variable, you will need to turn it into a character string and then read the result using the `INPUT` function.  For example:

```
data _null_;
  do EffectDate = 1130101,0130101;

     cEffectDate = put(EffectDate,z7.);
     if substr(cEffectDate,1,1) = '0'
         then SASEffectDate = input('19' || substr(cEffectDate,2),yymmdd8.);
         else SASEffectDate = input('20' || substr(cEffectDate,2),yymmdd8.);
     put EffectDate=
       / SASEffectDate=
       / ;
     end;
  format SASEffectDate yymmdd10.;
run;
```

This is just an illustration and a bit long-winded; it creates a new SAS variable named SASEffectDate to preserve the original variable.  Once you have it as a SAS variable, you don't need to do anything else; the SAS Access product will know how to make the references to the external database.

Here is an example of doing something similar using `PROC SQL`:

```
data have; /* Just a dummy data set for illustration */
  do EffectDate = 1130101,0130101;
     i+1;
     output;
     end;
run;
proc sql;
   create table want as
   select t2.*
        , case when t2.EffectDate < 999999 /* starts with 0 */
             then input('19' || substr(put(EffectDate,z7.),2),yymmdd8.)
             else input('20' || substr(put(EffectDate,z7.),2),yymmdd8.)
             end as SASEffectDate format=yymmdd10.
    from have t2
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: Interesting. How exactly is that integrated into a JOIN statement (in the ON criteria)? Also, the code being run is not SAS, it's SQL via 'proc sql' pulling from an external data source.

Comment: I guess I'm confused.  Is `EffectDate` a column in your DB2 table or is it a variable in a SAS data set?

Comment: EffectDate is a column in my DB2 table.

Comment: Oh; can you alter your question and show the kind of query you are trying to run?  It sounds like you need to do this in native DB2 code using `PROC SQL` "pass-through", correct?

Comment: Don't forget to move the results of your chat into the Answer for posterity :)